# AOP Pointcut to match Spring Step.execute(...) method

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-batch

I am attempting to use AspectJ AOP to intercept a call to a Spring Batch Step execution and advise on what file to log into.

Following the configuration in [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/), my pointcuts look like this:

```
@Before("execution(* org.springframework.batch.core.Step.execute(..)) && " + "args(stepExecution)")
public void setupLogging(Object stepExecution) {...}

@After("execution(* org.springframework.batch.core.Step.execute(..))")
public void tearDownLogging() {...}
```

Using the following test (and a similar one for when I tear down my logging), the pointcuts match, but do not seem to work when I try deploying them.

```
@Test
    public void testSetupLoggingMatcher() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
        java.lang.reflect.Method method = LoggingAspect.class.getMethod("setupLogging", Object.class);
        Annotation[] annotations = method.getDeclaredAnnotations();

        boolean matched = false;
        for (Annotation annotation: annotations) {
            if (annotation.annotationType() == org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before.class) {
                org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before beforeAnnotation = (org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before) annotation;
                String pointcutstring = beforeAnnotation.value();
                PointcutParser pointcutParser =
                        PointcutParser.getPointcutParserSupportingAllPrimitivesAndUsingContextClassloaderForResolution();
                Collection<PointcutParameter> parameters = new ArrayList<PointcutParameter>();
                parameters.add(new PointcutParameter() {

                    @Override
                    public Class getType() {
                        return StepExecution.class;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String getName() {
                        return "stepExecution";
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Object getBinding() {
                        return mockStepExecution;
                    }
                });
                PointcutExpression pointcut =
                        pointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(pointcutstring, LoggingAspect.class,
                                parameters.toArray(new PointcutParameter[0]));
                ShadowMatch match = pointcut.matchesMethodExecution(Step.class.getMethod("execute", StepExecution.class));
                matched = matched || match.alwaysMatches();
            }
        }
        assertTrue("No pointcuts on setupLogging matched Step.execute(StepExecution.class)", matched);
    }
```

I have verified that my pointcuts match the Step interface and that my Aspect is being initialized in the ApplicationContext. However, the pointcuts are not getting triggered when I try to run a job.  Why does this occur?  Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately ended up abandoning AOP and converting my former Aspect into a StepListener, which worked fine.

Comment: The main issue with your approach is that you have to manually inject your custom listener to all the steps of all the batches of your app...it smells boilerplate

Answer (score 1):

Your `execution()` pointcut matches method calls with an arbitrary number of arguments. Thus, you need to tell `args()` the position at which parameter `stepExecution` is to be found in relation to the others in order to make it match methods with more than one parameter, e.g.

- 1st parameter: `args(stepExecution, ..)`
- 2nd parameter: `args(*, stepExecution, ..)`
- 3rd parameter: `args(*, *, stepExecution, ..)`
- last parameter: `args(.., stepExecution)`

Comment: Execute is the sole parameter in the method I am trying to match, so I'll give the 1st parameter solution a shot.

Comment: No dice.  Your solution passed in a local test, but did not work when I deployed to the server.

Comment: Then you have a configuration or classloading issue.